# Determine the percentage area visible within a polygon from a visibility map with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, visibility

I'm using ArcGIS Pro and have created a visibility map for a specific area where a building will be built. I have 4 polygons buffered around the building at `1km`, `3km`, `5km` and `10km`.

How do I determine the percentage area where the building will be visible within each of the buffered polygons from the visibility map created?

I used a DEM to create a hillshade and then added a polygon for an outline around where the proposed building will be and also created the different buffers from there. I used the visibility 3D analyst tool to create the the visibility map (The observer points were placed around the polygon and elevation set to the height of the building). The layer created looks right, but now I need to use the visibility map created to determine the percentage visibility within each of the buffer polygons. I've attached a screenshot of my map (first picture) and will add an example from another source (second Picture) of what I need to happen.

[image: My map with the polygon and the buffer zones along with the visibility]

[image: I need to calculate the visibility like in the bottom left hand corner of this picture]

Comment: Can you be specific about which tools you used to get your visibility map and what kind of data it is now (vector, raster, file type?) What have you tried already? Some screenshots would be helpful as well.

Comment: Good day Jeffrey. I've updated my question and hope that this will explain my problem better.

Comment: What have you tried already? Coverage percentage would be calculated by the total area of the buffer zone/the area in green within that area. If you can get those two numbers you can calculate what you want. If you don't know what to try next, try clipping the raster to each buffer and running zonal statistics https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics-as-table.htm